# Windows 10 will not start

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

I am looking for help solving a problem where Windows 10 will not load on my Dell Inspiron 5770 laptop. The computer will turn on and show the post screen, but then it just sits there with the dots circling for hours. I've left it sit out overnight and it will still be circling the next morning. So far I restarted the computer multiple times, run the complete system scan and repair tools, but no luck yet. I have had the same problem before and did a factory reset, which solved the problem, but it is doing the same thing again. Resetting my computer every 3 months doesn't sound viable and I would like a permanent solution. The laptop once gave me the 0xc000001 code, which I believe is a system file or memory issue. Because of the possibility of a memory issue, I discovered my laptop has two disks (I did not order that feature) and found that the OS is on the smaller 100 GB drive and the 900 GB in the other drive is completely unused. I am wondering if moving the OS to the larger drive would help, and if so, how to go about moving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer has a hardware fault, most likely a faulty hard drive.

Certain Dell computers have built in diagnostics. You'll usually get to these pressing F12 during boot and choosing the appropriate option.

However, there are also well documented hardware diagnostic utilities which can perform these tests if your system does not have them.

UPDATE: If your computed does not include the built-in Dell hardware diagnostics, I recommend using the Ultimate Boot CD (https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html). It's got a lot of tools and can be overwhelming, but focus on the hard drive tests. You mostly want to check for bad sectors and SMART errors.

Absent this, you can take your computer to a competent local pc hardware technician for testing.

Comment: It was a bad hard drive like you said. I've since ordered a replacement. Thanks for the help.